# How to fix QML code editor auto-completion for integrated C++ methods in QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, qml, qt-creator

All!

In my QTCreator for QML code auto-completion for integrated C++ methods doesn't work.

For instance, I did Myclass class and pass object pointer to QML engine by setContextProperty method.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
Myclass* confptr = new Myclass();
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("testCPP", confptr);
```

In QML code after I input ...

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        spacing: 10

        Button {
            onClicked: testCPP.
```

... there is no auto-completion popup. So I need copy method name manually from C++ code.

After running application it works properly but manual inputs disturbs me.

Can you give an advice, how I can solve this problem?

**Myclass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class Myclass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int engineRPM READ engineRPM WRITE setEngineRPM NOTIFY engineRPMChanged)
public:
    Myclass();
    int engineRPM() const;

signals:
    void engineRPMChanged();

private:
    int m_engineRPM;

public slots:
    void setEngineRPM (int temp);

};



#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**Myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <QDebug>

Myclass::Myclass()
{
    setEngineRPM(100);
}

void Myclass::setEngineRPM (int temp){

    m_engineRPM = temp;
    qDebug () << "Some text here" << temp;
}

int Myclass::engineRPM() const{

    return m_engineRPM;

}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "myclass.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    Myclass* confptr = new Myclass();
    confptr->setEngineRPM(1);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("testCPP", confptr);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        spacing: 10

        Button {
            onClicked: testCPP.setEngineRPM(1000)
        }

        Text {
            text: testCPP.engineRPM
        }
    }
}
```

I have installed:

> Qt Creator 5.0.0 Based on Qt 5.15.2 (MSVC 2019, 64 bit)
>
> OS: Windows 10 21H1 build 19043.1415